# jquery dynamically add value for Attribute Filters?

Tags: jquery

I have Attribute Filter like this one:  `$(’input[name="email"]‘);`

I want to create a function with a parameter, which would contain the name of the attribute, something like this:

```
function test(id_new){
     var var_name = $("input[name='"+id_new+"']:checked").val();
    alert(var_name);
}
```

But this code is not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: What isn't working? var_name is being set to undefined?  What if you just try $("input[name='"+id_new+"']) in firebug...do you get a JQuery collection back?  What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of jQuery are you using? I'll assume 1.3.

Try removing the single quotes in the attribute selector:

```
function test(id_new){
     var var_name = $("input[name="+id_new+"]:checked").val();
    alert(var_name);
}
```

Comment: From JQuery Docs: Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the '@' symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again. So Vaske's syntax in that respect should be correct

Comment: Right, at first I was assuming he was using that syntax for an older version

Comment: That's pretty odd because there's really no reason that adding single quotes would cause a problem. Curious indeed...